# Amazon SNS with ruby, simple sms message

Tags: ruby, amazon-sns

I'm trying to send a simple sms from ruby directly to a phone number with the SNS service.

```
require 'aws-sdk'
sns = Aws::SNS::Client.new(region: 'my_region', access_key_id: 'my_id', secret_access_key: 'mykey')
sns.publish({phone_number: 'my_number', message: 'test message'})
```

but i get `ArgumentError: unexpected value at params[:phone_number]`

Comment: Is the phone number you're sending similar enough to a phone number?  I'm not looking for an exact number but I would presume "my_number" wouldn't work.

Comment: yes number, id and keys are proper values, and the format of the number is E.164 as aws wants

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The following example using a fictional UK mobile phone number in E.164 format works for me, are you sure you're passing `phone_number` in a string?

```
require 'aws-sdk'

sns = Aws::SNS::Client.new(...)
#=> #<Aws::SNS::Client>
sns.publish(phone_number: '+447911123456', message: 'test message')
#=> #<struct Aws::SNS::Types::PublishResponse...>
```

Comment: without region and aws secrets? Your example doesn't work for me

Comment: Well I've left those out, you should use your own. Are you getting the exact same error message? (in which case try updating the aws-sdk gem, I'm using the latest version).

Comment: It was the gem, i installed the latest version for my rails app , but locally i was testing with an older forgotten version. thank you!

Comment: The above code gives me this error
{ ArgumentError: unexpected value at params[:phone_number] }

Comment: @VivekTripathi, which Ruby/AWS-SDK version are you running?

Comment: aws 2.0.38 and
ruby 2.1.2

Comment: How to send Transactional SMS along with custom sender id with this ?

Answer (score 2):

If someone seeking for the answer of this Qn:

You can send SMS in 2 ways in AWS SNS.

1. Subscribe to a topic that is created in AWS SNS and send sms to all those numbers who had the subscription
2. Send SMS directly to a mobile number

What you need is the 2nd one.

I will demonstrate here how to do that with Ruby language.

Install the gem aws sns:

```
gem install aws-sdk-sns 
require 'aws-sdk-sns'
```

1.Set SNS client

```
@sns_client = Aws::SNS::Client.new(
  region: ENV['AWS_SNS_REGION'],
  access_key_id: ENV['AWS_SNS_ACCESS_KEY'],
  secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SNS_SECRET_KEY']
)
```

2.Set SNS client attributes

```
@sns_client.set_sms_attributes({
                                 attributes: {
                                   'DefaultSenderID' => SENDER_ID,
                                   'DefaultSMSType' => SMS_TYPE
                                 }
                               })
```

3.Publish SMS

```
@mobile_no = "+919888888888" # with country code

@sns_client.publish({
                      phone_number: @mobile_no,
                      message: MSG
                    })
```

thats it!

MSG: ‘Your message comes here’

SMS_TYPE : ‘Transactional’ or ‘Promotional’

If you want to send OTP / bank transactions, then it is ‘Transactional’. Else if you want to send some promotional sms of your product then it is ‘Promotional’

SENDER_ID: is the sender id that you have already registered if you want to use your own sender id.

If you don't have sender id skip the step 2 - Set SNS client attributes

AWS_SNS_REGION, AWS_SNS_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SNS_SECRET_KEY - are the credentials of your AWS account from where you would like to use SNS.

See the AWS documentation for this here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_publish-to-phone.html
It also provides code for Java language.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to send an SMS with AWS (assuming the from number is one you own in AWS Pinpoint).

```rb
    client = client = Aws::SNS::Client.new(
      region: ENV['AWS_SNS_REGION'],
      access_key_id: ENV['AWS_SNS_ACCESS_KEY'],
      secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SNS_SECRET_KEY']
    )

    response = client.publish(
      phone_number: "+1<your phone>",
      message: "something something",
      message_attributes: {
        "AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType" => {
          data_type: "String",
          string_value: "Promotional",
        },
        "AWS.MM.SMS.OriginationNumber" => {
          data_type: "String",
          string_value: "+1<AWS Pinpoint number>",
        },
      },
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone arriving here wondering how to send an SNS message in ruby, here's a minimal reproducible example (based off [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/developer-guide/sns-example-send-message.html)):

```rb
# Create topic

require 'aws-sdk-sns'  # v2: require 'aws-sdk'
sns = Aws::SNS::Resource.new(region: 'us-west-2')
topic = sns.create_topic(name: 'MyOtherTopic')


# Subscribe to it

sub = topic.subscribe({
  protocol: 'email',
  endpoint: 'your.email@example.com'
})


# Check your inbox and confirm subscription! (otherwise messages won't go through)


# Publish a message to it
topic.publish({
  message: 'Here is a cool message!'
})

# Check your email inbox!
```